# Specific enumeration style in Latex

Tags: lists

I want to have an algo in the document with enumerations like

Step I  g gjhf gjhf guhfd gfdjh gfd jh

Step II  s hfdjks hgfdkjfds hkfds hkfds hkjfds

Step III  jdsfkljdskl jfdskl jfdsl jfdsl jfds

How to achieve this enumeration style

Comment: have you checked `enumitem` package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \Roman*]` with package `enumitem` will do the tricks. If it is repreatedly used, it will be simpler to defined a new custom list, say `algo-enum` and say `\setlist[algo-enum]{label=Step \Roman*}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \roman*]
    \item todo 1
    \item todo 2
    \item todo 3    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

For Uppercase Roman letters use \Roman

[image]

But also for Algorithmns you might want to check our the `listing` package.

To make it more convenient, i expanded the example with Bernards comment and some more options to make it more like the proposed alignment.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{algo-enum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[algo-enum]{label=Step \Roman*,leftmargin=0pt, labelsep=1.5em,%
align=left, style=multiline,labelwidth=\widthof{Step XXXX}}
\begin{document}

\begin{algo-enum}
    \item todo 1. \\ which can be very deeply explained. \\
    Like this...
    \item todo 2
    \item todo 3    
\end{algo-enum}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: maybe you can expand your answer with Bernard's comment on how to create a new custom list at the preamble so it can used multiple times without having to re-define the labels on each `enumerate` environment

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem.